# Set Expiry Dates on PHP Application

Tags: php

I am working on a php application. I have generated an access code like license for the application, usually for one year from the date of installation.When the expiry date set in the DB is reached or about to be reached, it should give messages. Finally a day after expiration, should redirect to license page. The issue now is: When it has expired, it still show some days to expiry. Maybe my code is wrong or the way I select the day is wrong. Can anyone please assist.

```
    <?php
    $se = "SELECT * FROM license WHERE status=1 ORDER BY endDate DESC";
    $conf = mysqli_query($connection,$se);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($conf);
    $tday = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));
    $eday = new DateTime($row['endDate']);
    $interval =$eday->diff($tday);
    $diff =$interval->format("%a");
    $mth=$interval->m; 
    $days =$interval->d;
    if($diff<=90){
    print '<script type="text/javascript">';
    print 'alert("License has expired.Contact me for renewal: developer@yahoo.com or Technical Support: mobileNo")';
    print '</script>';

   }else if($diff<=45){
   print '<script type="text/javascript">';

   print 'alert("License has expired.Contact me for renewal: developer@yahoo.com or Technical Support: mobileNo")';
   print '</script>';

  }else if($diff<=0){
   print '<script type="text/javascript">';
    print 'alert("License has expired.Contact me for renewal: developer@yahoo.com or Technical Support: mobileNo")';
   print '</script>';
   echo "<script> document.location='License.php';</script>";
  }

?>
```

See the DB Record:
[image: DB Record]

Comment: do you want difference in days?

Comment: @RuchishParikh: Yes, I want differenc in days to compute

Comment: you can also use default date() and strtotime() to achieve it. @Dave

Comment: @RuchishParikh: Please, can you show me, as I have tried and it is still show I have 12days when it should be showing expired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should add `%R` when you format the interval: it will prefix format with `+` or `-`, which make it possible to compare with zero (for negative values):

```
$dif = $interval->format('%R%a');
```

Second, you always display the same message. And you don't compare in the correct order. You should compare like this:

```
switch (true) {
    case ($diff <= 0):
        // Expired, need renewal
        break;
    case ($diff <= 45):
        // Expires within the next 45 days
        break;
    case ($diff <= 90):
        // Expires within the next 90 days
        break;
}
```

You can use `if`/`elseif`/`else` statements if you like. But the order is important. And the message is important too :)

**UPDATE**

You need to calculate the correct difference:

```
$interval = $tday->diff($eday);
```

See it as :

```
$interval = $date_from->diff($date_to);
```

So if `$date_to` is greater than `$date_from`, the interval will be positive (`$date_to` is in `+$interval` days).

When `$date_to` was *before* `$date_from`, the interval will be negative (`$date_to` is in `-$interval` days, which means `$date_to` was `$interval` days ago).

So in your case, if `$interval` is positive, then the license will expire in `$interval` days. Else, license is expired for `$interval` days.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, but still not working. It still showed expires in 12days .

Comment: How can it display "expires in 12 days" whereas all messages in your code say "License has expired"? Please update your question with accurate code and samples you've tried.

Comment: What I am saying is this: From the Db, the expiry date is 2016-05-06. When compare with today. It should display Expired.Right? But based on the code, above, it displayed, License will expired in 45days.                                                      switch($diff) {
    case ($diff <= 0):
         echo "Expired, need renewal";
        break;
    case ($diff <= 45):
        echo " Expires within the next 45 days";
        break;
    case ($diff <= 90):
        echo "Expires within the next 90 days";
        break;

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.

- abs — Absolute value
- floor — Round fractions down

Try with `strtotime()`.

```
$date1 = "2016-05-07";  
$date2 = "2016-05-06";  
$diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));

$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));
echo $days . "days";
```

**Output**

```
1 days
```

Comment: That's very complicated whereas DateTime class is here to make it much easier, as OP did in his code...

Comment: @Ruchish Parikh: This was able to give me the difference of date in integer. However, I just discovered that this value is useful , but that won't get me the solution. WHat I wanted is this: if the today is >db expiry date, redirect to license screen. How can I achieve this.Please

Comment: Actually, `DateTime` is more accurate since it takes DST and leap years in consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. Your suggestion has helped me.All I should have done is to say:

```
<?php

    if($today>$db_expiry_date){
    redirect_to(license.php)
    }else{
    contine.....
    }
?>
```

Also, you can play around with the number of days left by using:

```
<?php
     if($diff<=45 && $today<$db_expiry_date){
        echo 'License will expire with next 45days';
        }elseif($diff<=90 && $today<$db_expiry_date){
        echo 'License will expire with next 90days';
        }else if($today>$db_expiry_date){
        echo 'License Expired';
        redirect_to('License.php');
        }
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on dbdate I have added to reminders which is alert before 1 day and 2 days. Its working on if else condition.

```
<?php
$expire = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('0 days'));
$alrt = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+2 days')); //renewal alert 1 day
$alrt2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+3 days')); //renewal alert 2 days

$dbDate = '2021-04-15';//expired
//$dbDate = '2021-04-16'; //1 day
//$dbDate = '2021-04-17'; //2 day

if (strtotime($dbDate) <= strtotime($expire))
{
    echo "<h2>subscription expired.</h2>";
    //
    
}
else if (strtotime($dbDate) > strtotime($expire))
{
    echo "<h2>Enjoy service.</h2>";
    if (strtotime($dbDate) < strtotime($alrt))
    {
        echo "<h2>expiring tommorow.please pay</h2>";
    }
    else if (strtotime($dbDate) < strtotime($alrt2))
    {
        echo "<h2>expiring in 2 days.please pay</h2>";
    }
    //
    
}

?>
```